# Install a previous version of pip3 on ubuntu debian9

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5, downgrade

Since I upgraded my pip3 from 9.0.1 to 10.1 to try to solve this problem
([python 3.5 in statsmodels ImportError: cannot import name '_representation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391868/python-3-5-in-statsmodels-importerror-cannot-import-name-representation)),

I can't manage to install any packages with pip3; it appears this is a problem caused by the latest version of pip3 with debian9.

So I try to solve it by installing the previous version of pip3. But I don't know how to do it. (I'm new on linux and I already block my PC twice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a specific version of pip using pip:
`pip3 install pip==9.0.3`