# cannot import name 'OLS' from 'statsmodels.formula.api'

Tags: python, importerror, statsmodels

I have this code:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import OLS
```

The error is as follows:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'OLS' from 'statsmodels.formula.api'

I tried updating statsmodels, but it does not work

Comment: `import statsmodels.api as sm; sm.OLS` ?

Comment: in fact, if I use that code, another error occurs: "DLL load failed:The specified module can not be found"

Comment: DLL load failed usually means that at least one of statsmodels, numpy, scipy or pandas is not correctly installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula API always uses lower case since these are functions and not classes, and so you can use

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
```

or the more canonical

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
smf.ols("y ~ x", df)
```